# Jquery Function to append variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am trying to append the value of *map* and *values* inside this *test* variable using a jQuery function ( which is at the end). How do I do this?

I want to change the value of *map: 'ecoMap'* to *map: developmentRegionMap* and *values: Chherti* to *values: testvalue*

```
function Eco_regions() {
    test = $('#world-map').vectorMap({
        map: 'ecoMap',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        regionsSelectable: false,
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: Chhetri,
                scale: ['#fffad6', '#d05300'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
        }
    });
};
```

This is the jquery function which is supposed to append the variable.

```
$('#change_ecoregions').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    test.map.setValue('developmentRegionMap');
    test.series.regions[0].setValues(testvalue);
    Eco_regions();
});
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? They could be of great use.

Comment: What is `test`, why does it exist before you call `Eco_regions` in the click handler? And what is that `vectorMap` plugin you're using?

Comment: So, you want to change the value of `map` after you've called `.vectorMap()`?  What is `vectorMap`?  What does it return? Are you sure the plugin will let you change its options?

Comment: What's with the `setValue()` and `setValues()`?

Comment: I'm assuming you're already initializing the vector map somewhere else before the `#change_ecoregions` element is clicked, so there shouldn't be a need to call `Eco_regions()` in your click function. So I would say it's a combination between @Haroldo_OK's answer and removing the superfluous call to reinitialize the map.

Answer (score 2):

What you require is plugin-specific; supposing you're using the [jQuery Vector Maps plugin](http://jqvmap.com/), according to the documentation, you'd have to do this in order to change values after the creation (untested):

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'map', 'developmentRegionMap');
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the value of map: 'ecoMap' to map: developmentRegionMap and values: Chherti to values: testvalue

Then just make them parameters of that function:

```
function Eco_regions(map, value) {
    test = $('#world-map').vectorMap({
        map: map || 'ecoMap',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        regionsSelectable: false,
        series: {
            regions: [{
                values: value || Chhetri,
                scale: ['#fffad6', '#d05300'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
        }
    });
};

$('#change_ecoregions').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Eco_regions('developmentRegionMap', testvalue);
});
```

Comment: Bergi, I already have the vector map working. What i am simply trying to do is use drop down menu to display different maps and plot different data on them. On selecting particular option form the drop down menu I want everything on the screen clear out and a  new map come. I could not figure out a way to do that ( just a beginner in jquery) so i thought that I would create a test variable so that i could change its value(by appending another set of data)  from a function and get my job done.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a great way to just change the variable and have it redraw the map. I think you might need to just blow the old map away and append a new one in.

1. Define an element for the map

   ```
   var mapElement = '<div id="world_map" style="width:600px; height: 400px;">';
   ```
2. Create a container div

   ```
   <div id="container"></div>
   ```
3. When the change event is fired, remove the old map, append a new element to the container, and call the `vectorMap` function with the new settings.

   ```
   $('#world_map').remove();
   $('#container').append(mapElement);
   $('#world_map').vectorMap(options);
   ```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUnre/2/) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a function `setValues` where, unless you've omitted some code, you haven't defined it. If you change it to `test.series.regions[0].values = testvalue;` you should have better luck. Also, without quotes, `testvalue` is undefined (unless it's global somewhere) so you'll either need to assign that variable some value or else surround it with quotes to make it a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to rearrange your function slightly so you can easily adjust the properties:

```
var test= {
    map: 'ecoMap',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    regionsSelectable: false,
    series: {
        regions: [{
            values: Chhetri,
            scale: ['#fffad6', '#d05300'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
        }]
    }
};

function Eco_regions(settings) {
    $('#world-map').vectorMap(settings);
};

$('#change_ecoregions').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    test.map = 'developmentRegionMap';
    test.series.regions[0] = testvalue;
    Eco_regions(test);
});
```